# WordPress rewrite rules not working

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

Based on the [WordPress rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), I want to change my URLs to user-friendly permalinks.
So I used WordPress tips in my functions.php but nothing happened!

I don't know it seems it's because of my link.

Here is my example page who should change the url:
[My sample page][2]

Here is my code in functions.php:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^music/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]&cmd=artist', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Actually I want to change this url:

```
page/?cmd=artist
```

to

```
/artists
```

or this url:

```
 page/?cmd=artist_detaile&id=31
```

to

```
 /dj-taba
```

So what's my mistake?

---

Problem solved by myself **

Answer (score 0):

Have u enabled `use permalinks` option in WP settings? If not do it.

Also u required to turn on rewrite mode on .htaccess file or directly in server conf file.

I hope it gonna help.

Comment: yes i did it before. also my .htaccess file is using wordpress default rules (settings > permalinks).